# Getting Facebook Photo Likes Count Without FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Facebook FQL is deprecated. I'm currently using it to get the total sum of likes / comments photos have.

I'm doing something like this:

```
$q = "SELECT like_info, object_id, comment_info FROM photo WHERE object_id IN(".implode(",", $object_ids) .")";
```

Now that FQL is deprecated, how can I do the same with the graph API ?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy with the Graph API:

```
/{photo-id}?fields=likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)
```

Comment: hmm, that's just for one photo at a time, but it seems if I add `fields=likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)` to the main `/{uid}/photos` graph api query, I can get that info directly there. Thanks, that seems like a solution for me!